# How do i substitute a value into a polynomial in Magma (CAS)?

Tags: magma-cas

I have the following code

> R := PolynomialRing( Integers() );
>   i:=2^6-1;
>   a:=Intseq(i,2);
>   f:=Polynomial(a);
>   f;   //resulting in X^5 + X^4 + X^3 + X^2 + X + 1

I would like to replace the terms of the polynomial X with an integer, let's say 3 or 4?
I tried these:

> f1 := f where X is 3;
>   f1;
>   Result(f,3);
>   R := PolynomialRing(f,3);

none of which are giving the desired integer result.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, what you want is the evaluation of the polynomial at the given values.  Thus:

```
Evaluate(f, 3);
```

Comment: Yes exactly it is what I want. Thanks, it works!!